# How can I create a custom sized disk using LXC

Tags: containers, diskspace, lxc, lxd

Good day,

I have been looking through a lot of documentation and nothing really appears to confirm how to expand the disk size of the the LXC containers that I am spinning up..

Here is what I have tried so far,

I warn you the items below look unrelated, but confirm my thoughts that it is and should be possible to alter the disk size.

[LXC how to change network adapters](https://blog.simos.info/how-to-make-your-lxd-container-get-ip-addresses-from-your-lan/)

I followed the document with hopes that I could modify the size of the /  and judging from this question it looks like it is possible...

https://askubuntu.com/questions/779609/lxd-container-disk-and-block-i-o-limits-edit-its-a-zfs-pool-limit

I tried doing this and It does write to the config , but the configuration never takes.

```
lxc profile device set tuleapprofile root size 20GB
lxc launch -p tuleapprofile images:centos/6/amd64 tuleap
```

**TULEAP PROFILE**

```
lxc profile show  tuleapprofile 
config: {}
description: Default LXD profile
devices:
  eth0:
    name: eth0
    nictype: bridged
    parent: lxdbr0
    type: nic
  root:
    path: /
    pool: default
    size: 20GB
    type: disk
name: tuleapprofile
used_by: []
```

**df -h**

```
                      8.9G  188M  8.8G   3% /
none                  492K     0  492K   0% /dev
udev                  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/full
udev                  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/null
udev                  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/random
udev                  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/tty
udev                  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/urandom
udev                  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/zero
udev                  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/fuse
udev                  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/net/tun
tmpfs                 100K     0  100K   0% /dev/lxd
tmpfs                 100K     0  100K   0% /dev/.lxd-mounts
tmpfs                 3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
```

All I want is to have / in the LXC containers be larger (by 20 G ) so I can install what I need. how can I do this. The method doesn't really matter , but I would like to have this.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I guess your question will fit better in [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), if you will post it there, then please delete this post to avoid cross domain posting, thanks

Comment: what storage backend are you using?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I am not sure I know how to answer your question , It was a typical installation on ubuntu , has lxd and zfs for the fs I think. How can I find out and give you the answer you need?

Comment: With `dir` you cant use disk quotas, whats `lxc info | grep storage:` show?

Comment: The storage is ZFS .  lxc info | grep storage:
  storage: zfs